How to permanently disable "Secure Keyboard Entry" for terminal
Related to Touch ID window for sudo doesn't get focus when opened from iTerm
Every time I restart Terminal I have to remember to turn off "Secure keyboard entry".
I did try adding Terminal to the Privacy and Security, Input monitoring, I think that does the opposite of what I want, so added it (didn't work) and turned it off (didn't work).
And tried adding sudo (didn't work).
